# Confusing about python byte literal

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python3, what I know about byte literal is that

- whenever a single byte can be represented by printable **ASCII** character, it will be shown as this character. e.g `b'\x63\xf8'` will be `b'c\xf8'`
- Recently, I found that there is some strange property. It seems that number (if each digit less than 8 and length of all digits <= 3) after `\` will be seen as **octal**, e.g `b'\123' == b'S'` but it seems largest is `b'\377' == b'\xff'`. However, `b'\474' == b'<', b'\574' == b'|'`

Can anyone explain strange behavior above second property? What is general rule for byte with form of some number following `\`?

Comment: `0o474 == 316` and `316 % 256 == 60` and `chr(60) == '<'`. Bytes have values only up to `256` so if the number represented is bigger than 256 only the first 8 bits are kept. IMHO this should be a bug (I'd expect an invalid escape exception or something)... maybe the cost of checking for the validity of the value is too big and not worth paying and hence this implementation

Comment: @00 Actually the description says nothing of *literals*. It is describing byte objects and, as the issue you linked describes, `bytes((0o407,))` does raise a `ValueError` as described. The documentation does not say that the literal `\407` will trigger a `ValueError` (and in fact I'd expect to get a `SyntaxError` for invalid literal at compile time... not a `ValueError` at runtime).

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Thanks.Isn’t of single byte highest value 255?

Comment: @Spaceship222 here (for Python), yes. See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes . Arguably, there are signed and unsigned bytes, but Python uses unsigned bytes.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Thanks, that was poor reading on my side. The sentence starts with "While byte literals [...]", but then continues after the comma with ", bytes objects actually [...]". I'll note that in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the CPython implementation.

The [documentation about bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) states the following:

> While bytes literals and representations are based on ASCII text, bytes objects actually behave like immutable sequences of integers, with each value in the sequence restricted such that 0 <= x < 256 (attempts to violate this restriction will trigger `ValueError`).

Technically, this mentions bytes objects, not bytes literals, so the extrapolation could be seen as invalid, that is, `b'\407'` does not have to behave the same as `bytes((0o407,))` (and indeed, it doesn't currently).

This behaviour was [filed as a bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue37367) only fairly recently (June 2019). A fix is incoming, but appears to be scheduled for Python 3.9 only, and will raise a `ValueError` for `b'\407'`.

It is unclear to me whether there will be bugfix releases for existing versions (including 3.8, which is in beta); possibly not, because this may change results for software that relies on this behaviour.

(For the more curious: here's the current submitted patch: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/14654 .)